# How to check if view has tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, null

Help me pls with this unexpected trouble.

```
if (view.tag != nil)
```

^^ this worked for me, but suddenly i've assigned 0 tag to the view, and now everything's broken.

How can i check if view has a tag assigned ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> All views have a tag. default is Zero 0

It depend on what you have. I believe you should consider a view with tag 0 is a view that is not tagged. and start tagging from 1.

Since the tag property of a view is of type `NSInteger` it can not be `nil`. `NSInteger` is a primitive type and therefore can not have a `nil` pointer. The default value assigned to the property will be `0`.

**Also, when you compare nil with 0 it gives a YES in objective-c. Thats what is breaking your logic.**

`if (view.tag != nil)` equivalent to `if (view.tag != 0)`

Comment: We should add that the default value is 0 because tag is a primitive type, `NSInteger`, which can not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

tag is non-negative value. if you don't set tag of a view then it's default tag is 0. so, you have always a tag associate with a view.

in this regards, if you set tag>0 then you can check

```
if(tag>0){
  //do something
}else{
 //this is not your view
```

}

But you can't check

```
if (view.tag != nil)// because nil compares with object and if that object not found then return nil. if you compare with it nil value with an integer number it will also return 0. you will get a unexpected result.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to understand:

1. Tag is an unsigned integer, which is a *primitive* type, and `nil` is used to test for an unassigned *object* type.
2. The compiler will consider `nil` to be `0` in this context, which is the reason it doesn't "fire".

Solution:

1. Assign `tag > 0`.
2. Test using `if (view.tag > 0) { ... }`.